# Is it possible to set Chrome as the default browser in Windows via a script?

Tags: script

Each time I log into my work computer, my profile is built / set up and Edge is set as the default browser.

I then go into "Default apps" ("Settings" is restricted due to my system settings) and set Chrome as my default browser and I have to do this each time as it only lasts for the duration of the session.

Is it possible to build a script that I can run which performs this action when I run it?

I have looked at Task Scheduler but am unable to achieve it via this method.

Note: I am debating whether this question belongs on Super User or StackOverflow but decided to post it here on Super User as it is less of a coding-related question and more of a system-functionality-related question.

Comment: If in Settings you have set Chrome as default browser, this is supposed to stick. Where exactly in Settings do you do it?

Comment: That is (was) my understanding also but it never does on this system.  The option to do so via Settings specifically isn't actually available (due to system restrictions) so I go in via "Default apps" and set it that way (I'll add this into the question).  Each time I log out and back in again, my profile is rebuilt and Edge is set as the default browser each time, hence my desire for a script that I can run each time I log in to achieve this.

Comment: The default apps are saved in registry. But some W10 versions ago Microsoft added a protection to those registry keys to prevent unauthorized overwriting by apps (AFAIR there is a second entry created by Windows itself which "signs" the data). Therefore you can try to set the default browser via Windows settings and then export those registry entries (value + signature). And after logon reimport them. As these are the original settings Windows will hopefully accept them.

Comment: @Robert I just tried and editing the registry is restricted on my system, unfortunately!

Comment: You mean regedit is restricted on your system read/write of the registry is still possible by third party tools or e.g. PowerShell. Then most likely you are in a corporate environment and the changed default web browser is caused by a Group Policy. Therefore talk to your admins.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I believe that it is set by a Group Policy and I will speak to the admins, but the question still remains - is it possible to script what I am doing manually each time?  It isn't restricted, so is therefore permitted, meaning that it _could_ be scripted by replicating each step of the process.  (How) Can this be done?

Comment: @SnookerFan - It’s only possible if you are an Administrator